# Скажите плиз как реализовать

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика

Нужно найти разницу между суммой всех цифр использованных для записи всех нечетных чисел от 1 до х и суммой всех цифр использованных для записи всех четных четных чисел от 1 до х. Вводится х. 
Пример:
Ввод: 4
Вывод: -2

Comment: Не пугайте рябенка минусами, изверги! Разность суммы нечетных и суммы четных в диапазоне натуральных чисел? Реализовать так - бежишь по диапазону в цикле с шагом 1 и суммируешь четные в одно число, нечетные в другое, а потом, после цикла, находишь их разность. Профит и пятёрка )

Answer (score 2):

Вариант тупой - перебор:

```
int digSum(int N)  // Подсчет суммы цифр в числе
{
    int sign = (N%2 == 0) ? -1 : 1;
    int sum = 0;
    while(N)
    {
        sum += N%10;
        N/=10;
    }
    return sum*sign;
}

int dumb(int N)     // Просто цикл...
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
        sum += digSum(i);
    return sum;
}
```

Вариант чуточку поумнее - считать только не более 9 чисел, пользуясь тем, что разница для чисел, заканчивающихся на 9, в общем-то, почти очевидна:

```
int smart(int N)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int d = (N+1)/10;
    sum = d*5;
    for(int i = (N+1)/10*10; i <= N; ++i)
        sum += digSum(i);
    return sum;
}
```

Еще умнее возможно, но нет столько времени, чтоб сидеть, писать и отлаживать. И так получается ничего :)

Comment: а умнее - заметить, что все числа можно сгруппировать {0,1} {2,3} {4,5} и поэтому ответ будет `x/2 - x&1?0:x`

Comment: @pavel Ну я же говорил :) Только руки не дошли...